# How to implement Server-Sent Events on IOS using Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am trying to listen the firebase events using rest api.The problem is the callback method is not called. I am using [EventSource](https://github.com/inaka/EventSource) for this purpose.Is this the correct way to listen the events?

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: { (token, error) in
    let server : String =  "https://project-XXXXX.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=\(token!)"

    let eventSource: EventSource = EventSource(url: server)
    eventSource.onOpen {
        // When opened
        debugPrint("eventSource open")
    }

    eventSource.onError { (error) in
        // When errors
        debugPrint("error = \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    eventSource.onMessage { (id, event, data) in
        debugPrint("data = \(data)")
        // Here you get an event without event name!
    }

    eventSource.addEventListener("child_added") { (id, event, data) in
        debugPrint("data = \(data)")
        // Here you get an event 'event-name'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I have to add 'put' event listener instead of 'child_added' event listener. According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-streaming), we can use only following event listener:

- put
- patch
- keep-alive
- cancel
- auth_revoked

(Reference: https://github.com/inaka/EventSource/issues/86#issuecomment-354029202 )